# Removing HashSet with Object

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

When I try to remove a `HashSet` that takes an object, the `hashset.contains(Object)` and `iterator.equals(Object)` are always false, even when they should be true.

```
public boolean removeElement(Element element)
{        
    Iterator<Element> itr = elements.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Element oldElement = itr.next();
        if (itr.equals(new Element(element.eString, element.eInt, element.eBoolean))) {
            itr.remove();
            return true;
        }
        if (elements.contains(new Element(element.eString, element.eInt, element.eBoolean))) {
            elements.remove(new Element(element.eString, element.eInt, element.eBoolean));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this a feature of Java, a bug, or am I simply coding this wrong? This seems like the logical solution to removing, but it always fails without throwing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
itr.equals(new Element(element.eString, element.eInt, element.eBoolean))
```

This will *always* return false because you're comparing an `Iterator` to an `Element` which are completely different types of objects. You want to compare the element to `itr.next()` which you have saved previously to a local variable.

```
if (elements.contains(new Element(element.eString, element.eInt, element.eBoolean))) {
```

This would return false as well if you didn't override the `equals()` method in the class `Element`. The default `Object.equals()` method is used which dictates that the two references should refer to the *same* object in order to be equal. In this case, you're comparing against a new object that you create using `new Element(element.eString, element.eInt, element.eBoolean)`. To solve this you need to override the `equals` method to specify how the objects of type `Element` must be checked for equality.

For example, if `Element` has the following fields:

```
String eString;
int eInt;
boolean eBoolean;
```

Then you can override `equals` as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Element other = (Element) obj;
    if (eBoolean != other.eBoolean)
        return false;
    if (eInt != other.eInt)
        return false;
    if (eString == null) {
        if (other.eString != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!eString.equals(other.eString))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: But simple code that doesn't even check `equals()` fails, for example: `boolean removed = elements.remove(new Element(element.eString, element.eInt, element.eBoolean)); return removed;`

Comment: To clarify: fixing the `itr.equals...` to `oldGreeter.equals...` fixed my problems, I am simply wondering why the `boolean removed...` doesn't work.

Comment: @OP: The `HashSet.remove()` uses your class' `equals()` method internally to perform the remove operation.  So it will fail for the same reason.